# Windows batch script to find string from html file and copy it to text file

Tags: batch-file

So, i have html file with a line like:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"> fid="RandonString"; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script>
```

My task is to find **fid="RandomString"** and copy everything between "" to a text file without using any external software.
RandonString is 2-100 characters long.

Comment: I'd suggest using VBScript/JScript (via Windows Scripting Host) instead of BAT/CMD since you're working with a file that contains special characters. It's not that you can't do it with BAT/CMD. It's just that it'll be difficult and trouble some.

Comment: ok... Any suggestion how make it with VBScript.

Comment: Check here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176792.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But i only need this one script so it's bit too much to start learning from the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not all that hard, here's a 5 line solution:

```
set "x=<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"> fid="RandonString"; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script>"
set "x=%x:*fid=%"
set "x=%x:";="&rem %
set  x=%x:~2%
echo %x%
```

---

An explanation of what is going on.

You have to deal with 5 special characters, the `<`, `>`, `=`, `"` in your string, and the `&` character used to trim trailing data.

**Lines 1-3:** `<>` are both redirection characters, so to deal with them, it's required that the **whole** variable be surrounded by doublequotes (`"`). **BUT** you don't want the double quotes to be added to the variable itself.

**Line 1** By putting the first quote **before** the variable to be set ( "`x=`), and the second one **after** the data to be set (`<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"> fid="RandonString"; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script>`" ), the command **SET** recognises that the quotes are not to be included in the variable. Thus variable data with special characters can be set without errors. (Putting the quotes inside the variable data will work too, but adds 2 special characters to the variable data and makes dealing with other search & replace commands more difficult.)

**Line 2** The next step is to remove everything up to and including `fid`, `*fid` matches everything up to `fid`, the `=%` replaces it with nothing.

**Line 3** The next step is to to remove everything after `";`, this requires a little hack. The command processor can be tricked into doing this by adding `="&rem %` to the search and replace. The '=' tells the command processor to replace `;"` with the following characters, but the next character is `"`, which makes the preceding set command a quoted command, and means that the special `&` character is not quoted, leaving it available to be interpreted. This essentially puts everything after the `&` on a separate line, and so the search and replace command replaces `";` with nothing. The `REM` statement is there to make sure the data that comes after the matched `";` is not interpreted as a command and also means that any redirection characters will be ignored.

So what the command processor sees is:

```
set x=="RandonString
rem "; v_width=620; v_height=490;</script>
```

Which sets `x` to `="RandonString`

**Line 4** Now we have a problem since `%x%` begins with `="`, and both `=` and `"` are special characters, with `=` being especially hard to match. But, luckily we **know** that the string now starts with `="`, so the solution is simple. We simply skip the first two characters by telling the command processor to start with the 2nd character (character 0 currently = `=`, character 1 currently = `"`, so character 2 = `R`). Therefore, since **Line 2** removed everything (including any redirection characters) up to and including `fid`, and **Line 3** removed everything including `";` to the end of the string (including any redirection characters),
`%x:~2%` = `RandonString`. With all the redirection characters removed, the variable does not need to be quoted at all.

**Line 5** Just echo's the variable `x`.