# Find & copy a string in a file using only Windows batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I call the file I want to search in *input.txt* and the string I want to find *mystring*.

Example content of input.txt [(real input.txt)](http://pastebin.com/xD8ZCsE3)

```
randomstring1<>"\/=:
randomstring2<ORIGINAL>mystring</ORIGINAL>randomstring3
```

- *mystring* is surrounded by the strings `<ORIGINAL>` and `</ORIGINAL>` that must be  searched for
- The string between both `ORIGINAL`-tags should be copied to clipboard (using | clip)
- *mystring* and the tags occur only once. But they have no fixed position
- all strings can contain special characters (<, >, ", \, /, =, :)

I read a lot of [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973880/windows-batch-script-to-find-string-from-html-file-and-copy-it-to-text-file) but to be honest: the FOR-loop and SET-command syntax was too awkward for me. I guess my best shot will be the FINDSTR command. But maybe it is also possible with some help of RegEx expressions.

I do **not** want to use VBscript, Powershell, SED, FART, AWK, grep or any other additional tool.

Please be so kind and explain the difficult parts if you post a solution.
I want to understand it and maybe its helpful for others too.

My last attempt before I've given up was this *test.cmd*

```
@echo off
set "x=randomstring1<>"\/=:randomstring2<ORIGINAL>mystring</ORIGINAL>randomstring3"
set "x=%x:*<ORIGINAL>=%"
set "x=%x:</ORIGINAL>*=%"
set  x=%x:~2%
echo %x%
pause
```

Comment: *‘the FOR-loop and SET-command syntax was too awkward for me’* – sadly, many features of Windows batch scripting can appear awkward. Some of them keep looking awkward even after you get used to them, especially if you know how much easier/clearer solutions may be in other scripting tools or languages. However that may be for you, the FOR /F loop and the SET /P assignment are probably the two most fundamental native devices for processing text files line by line in Windows batch scripting. Meaning you had better get used to them. :) And, who knows, they might eventually grow on you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem Let findstr to find the LINE you want (only once):
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "<ORIGINAL>" input.txt') do set "line=%%a"
ECHO LINE: "%line%"
rem Change left delimiter by {
set "line=%line:<ORIGINAL>={%"
rem Change right delimiter by }
set "line=%line:</ORIGINAL>=}%"
ECHO STRING DELIMITED: "%LINE%"
rem Get second token delimited by { and }
for /F "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ("%line%") do set string=%%a
ECHO STRING: "%STRING%"
rem Copy string to clipboard
REM echo %string%| clip
```

Output:

```
LINE: "randomstring2<ORIGINAL>mystring</ORIGINAL>randomstring3"
STRING DELIMITED: "randomstring2{mystring}randomstring3"
STRING: "mystring"
```

As an option, you may delete from beginning of line until left delimiter:

```
set "line=%line:*<ORIGINAL>=%"
```

... and get the FIRST token separated by any delimiter you wish (ie: }):

```
for /F "delims=}" %%a in ("%line%") do set string=%%a
```

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "mystring" input.txt')`. This searches for "mystring", right?. But "mystring" is unknown and can not be searched for. It is surrounded by <ORIGINAL> and </ORIGINAL>. Maybe my description is misleading?

Comment: Ops! My mistake, I was somewhat absentminded... Just change "mystring" by "<ORIGINAL>" in the findstr command; I already did that in the program above and tested it: the output is the same ;-)

Comment: **Its case sensitive** =D Thank you very much (ORIGINAL > original)

Comment: I doubt there is no silly trick so that FINDSTR will search a string inside a variable instead of searching inside a file?

Comment: @nixda: Just pass the variable value to FINDSTR as filter: `echo %variable% | findstr ...`, but in this case the result would be just the same value or nothing depending if the search string is inside the variable or not...

Comment: first attempt: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "<original>" "%variable%" ') do set "line=%%a"` ----- second attempt:`for /F "delims=" %%a in ('echo %variable% | findstr "<original>" ') do set "line=%%a"` <- you mean this way?